# I need help interpreting MCA plots and data for a large language research project

Tags: data-visualization, multivariate-analysis, interpretation, correspondence-analysis

I posted on the site a few days ago about my research and got some good advice from several users who suggested that an MCA was the most appropriate way to analyze my data (thank you btw!).  I have since then used SPSS to generate an MCA.  The problem I now face is trying too sus out what is relevant/important from what is not.  The research is exploratory/discovery oriented, so I am not out to prove a hypothesis, just looking for patterns and strong connections between variables.

From my very basic understanding of this method of analysis, points on the chart which are close together are strongly related, and those far apart are not, however I'm aware of how obtuse that sounds, (not to mention I clearly can't write "these two variables were close together" in a formal paper, lol)

So what I'm asking now, is for anyone who is well-versed in MCA to give me the "broad strokes" of how you go about interpreting the results. I'm interested in knowing things such as "how close do two points need to be to be considered significant?" "how confident can I be in these results?"  and "what figures would any statisticians expect to see/want to see in a paper that uses an MCA?

While I can find p-values, SD and perform simple t-tests, that's about all my statistical education covers and I'm waaaaay out of me element here and I feel like I'm drowning....

I'll post the scatterplot and some other results below if it helps.  Each case (row in the data) was a single utterance produced by a student.  There were two types of variables; the topic of conversation, and speech acts which happened within the utterance. The 9 points in ALL CAPS represent themes of conversation, and all the other points represent different speech acts.

Edit: I should mention one important change I made to the chart that probably effects how it might be interpreted; each variable was binary, it either was present in a case (yes) or it wasn't (no).  As each case (utterance) on average only contained 1~4 speech acts, and there are 39 speech acts, most of the speech acts would contain a value of 1 for "no" in the table.  This of course resulted in all of the plots for "no" categories for speech act variables to cluster around the origin in a big mess. For readability, and because I am not interested in when speech acts did NOT occur, I have omitted them from the chart.

[image: scatterplot]

[image: model summary]

[image: correlations original variables]

I don't expect anyone to look very closely at that last one, I'm just including it to give an idea of what data I have. I have other data as well.